# Declaring variable in PL/SQL when Commit transaction

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqltransaction

I try to write this transaction in Oracle Developer:

```
DECLARE @UserID int:
SET @UserID = 2323;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM OWNER.TABLE
WHERE USER_ID = @UserID;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

But `int` is red - error say about there is no in or out

Comment: Oracle and tsql?!? One tag should be removed...

Comment: if this is copy/pasted the problem would be the colon after `int` which should be a semicolon

Comment: I change to semicolon but still is wrong :(

Comment: If you are trying to run T-SQL (or PL/SQL) in Oracle's SQL Developer are you running it using either the "Green arrow" button or the keyboard shortcut `CRTL-Enter` to run each statement individually or running it as a script using the "Green arrow with a page behind it" button or the keyboard shortcut `F5`? You ought to be running it as a script.

Comment: i INDICATE THEN IT IS WRONG AFTER RUN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is tagged Oracle and you say you are using Oracle Developer...

The syntax you are using is entirely wrong for an Oracle database - you appear to be trying to use code intended for SQL SERVER.

Re-writing it for oracle can be as simple as:

```
DELETE FROM OWNER.TABLE
WHERE USER_ID = 2323;

COMMIT;
```

However, if you particularly need a bind variable then:

```
VARIABLE UserID NUMBER;

BEGIN
  :UserID := 2323;
END;
/

DELETE FROM OWNER.TABLE
WHERE USER_ID = :UserID;

COMMIT;
```

or (using a pl/sql variable):

```
DECLARE
  UserID OWNER.TABLE.USER_ID%TYPE := 2323;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM OWNER.TABLE
  WHERE USER_ID = UserID;

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

However, if it is SQL Server then this works:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13364/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( User_ID INT );

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 2322 );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 2323 );

DECLARE @UserID INT = 2323;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE  User_ID = @UserID;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13364/1/0)**:

```
| User_ID |
|---------|
|    2322 |
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
DECLARE @UserID int;  set @UserID = 2323
```

Comment: in which language your are trying this

Comment: I use Oracalce Developer

Comment: sorry for that, you should be mention orcal tag